# How to export chat text in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to automatically (either with Teams or with third party tools) log a user's Microsoft Teams chats to files on his local system? Much like how it was possible with Sametime, Skype, AOLIM etc.?

Comment: Do you want to export the chats to a file?

Comment: The export process is outlined in [Teams: Replace Old Account with New](https://superuser.com/a/1762446/369805).

Comment: The export process is outlined in [Replace Old Account with New](https://superuser.com/a/1762446/369805).

Answer (score 1):

A very long and detailed description of the process is found in the article
[How to export MS Teams chat to HTML file (for backup)](https://www.psguy.eu/how-to-export-ms-teams-chat-to-html-file-for-backup/).

The article itself is much too long to describe here, and it helpfully
contains screenshots for every step of the way.
Most of the described steps only need be done once, and the final step
that can be repeated is in the form of a PowerShell script.

This process was automated in the Github project of
[Microsoft Teams chat backup](https://github.com/edgraaff/teams-chat-backup),
described as:

> This project retrieves a full chat history (messages and uploaded files) and renders it as a HTML.

The project requires `node.js` version 10 or higher.
It was tested on macOS, but will most likely run on Linux and probably on Windows.

Both the article and the Github project require an Auth token (JWT)
for calling Microsoft Graph APIs.
This token is generated via Microsoft's
[Graph Explorer website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same problem. **You can't extract/export or even share a MicrosoftTeams Chat History**.

For what I recall, a network office administrator might be able to export "group" chats. **Please note that these group chats are not the same as conversations with multiple people.**
I had to copy-paste entire multiple conversations, in order to share those conversations with my superior, and even while copy-pasting, I found out that I'm limited on the number of messages I can copy. I could only copy like 10 messages at a time which made the task pretty hard and time consuming.

There is already a lot of posts, on MicrosoftForums, Reddit and here about this situation, and it seems that in the near future MicroSoft will "fix" this.

*Microsoft believes that users are entitled to their privacy and an administrator shouldn't be able to export a user or group's conversation, **but the user should be able to do it himself/herself if he/she wants to**.*

I came across some Microsoft forums and some blogs which might be handy for you:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/saving-conversations-in-teams/m-p/38043

https://regroove.ca/stellark/2019/07/02/how-to-export-ms-teams-chat-history/

Answer (score 0):

For MS Teams (free), log in to the account privacy area to [Export my personal Teams Data](https://privacy.teams.live.com/ui/en/dataexport). Get the very nice [Export my Data](https://privacy.teams.live.com/ui/en/dataexport) page that looks like this:
[image: Teams Export Options]
Download the message viewer linked at the bottom of the page to view the exported items. The export itself may take a while, to check it, duplicate the tab to access the zipped **tar** of json files.
Unfortunately, at this time, channel content is not part of any export process, might be an opening for third party software at [Partners](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/partners), for example.