# Replace Old Email Account with New Email Account

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, microsoft-teams

Have an email account to be retired, and wish to continue MS Teams (free, classic) as before with an existing MS Live account.

To sign in with a different account is as with a new user, and there are no options in the gui for resuming either current team activity, or activities for other accounts.

Right now, one way appears to be with using [Exchange Online Remote PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/basic-auth-connect-to-exo-powershell?view=exchange-ps) , undergoing deprecation, another way is to employ the more up-to-date [Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps).

The best bet is a guide linked [here](https://www.tecklyfe.com/change-office-365-group-or-team-email-address/) (no gui), not sure if this works with MS Teams **(free)**, see last comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft Live (personal) accounts are not Office 365 (work) accounts. I believe for Live accounts, you can add another email address (alias), and then remove the old one. Check out some of the support steps here: https://support.microsoft.com/home/contact?linkquery=Change%20the%20email%20address%20or%20phone%20number%20for%20your%20Microsoft%20account - Make sure to test logging in with the new address in Teams/outlook/etc

Comment: @Cpt.Whale: Have two MS email accounts, the main is at the live address, the secondary one is used in teams. Want to replace the secondary with the main, hence the issue. Not sure if removing the secondary will brick teams activity altogether.

Comment: Looks like it's pretty much the same process to change the teams (free) account email address: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-phone-number-or-email-address-in-microsoft-teams-free-ac25973e-ad82-41c8-a8f8-47bf40c69580?WT.mc_id=365AdminCSH_Smc

Comment: Okay because we are switching to primary, pressing the big red button to delete the existing teams email address won't remove the Teams history? In that case, later, the old address can be re-added to MS Account in case it's required again.

Comment: I doubt it removes your own chat history, since the account stays the same. It does mention other people won't be able to search for you by the old email though. Maybe you can export your messages to be safe, or contact their support for specifics

Comment: Only channel content is required- nothing in the chat tab here. Getting an "Our services aren't available right now" when [exporting](https://account.microsoft.com/privacy/export)- would their [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/export-teams-content)s work from something like AHK? (maybe another question to be asked here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is linked to [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/issues-with-activation-links-in-organization/60a4e778-6654-4cc1-a8e5-affa0ef41a4b) which explains a few of the issues in the OP here, which goes off at a bit of a tangent due to bad google-fu.

Even though it was not specified in the question, an [org-wide team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/create-an-org-wide-team) is the one under consideration, insofar as the only way to leave the team is to leave the org.
Because the email address of an organizational or work (school may be the same) account cannot be changed from *either* within or without Teams Free (Classic), switching accounts for an organization is undertaken by [leaving the organization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/leave-a-teams-free-classic-organization-a8fd9675-fb0c-4e64-81a5-c6f155657462) for the outgoing account, and activating a link in an invitation from the owner (or tenant) of the organization to the incoming account. The order of leave/activate may not be important, as long as (from personal experience) Teams is not quit and restarted with two of your accounts active.

Account removal via Microsoft Account is an alternative to leaving, the effect in Teams is not reflected until the next Teams/system restart.